# Ranking and Grouping

Tags: sql-server

This is how I would like my code to look like:

```
 publshrID   BkID_Title    BkID_Title     BkID_Title  BkID_Title
    ----     ----          ------         ------       -------
    9000     1502 Book#1   1301 Book#2    1101 Book#3  1402 Book#4
    9042     1304 Book#1   1201 Book#2    1101 Book#3  1402 Book#4
```

This is the code I've written

```
WITH BKS AS(
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by pb.publ_id order by BK.list_price DESC) AS RankN,
           PB.publ_id AS publ,
           CONVERT(varchar(25),book_id)+ ' '+ title AS Main
           FROM bkinfo.publishers AS PB
           INNER JOIN bkinfo.books AS BK ON PB.publ_id = BK.publ_id
           )
SELECT BKS.publ,
       CASE WHEN RankN = 1 THEN MAIN ELSE '' END AS a,
       CASE WHEN RankN = 2 THEN MAIN ELSE '' END AS b,
       CASE WHEN RankN = 3 THEN MAIN ELSE '' END AS c,
       CASE WHEN RankN = 4 THEN MAIN ELSE '' END AS d
FROM BKS
```

It's not quite right. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is the problem or what do you mean NOT QUITE RIGHT?

Comment: What has gone wrong here? Looks like you would be interested in DENSE_RANK() Over some partition what you are doing.

Comment: He/She wants the 4 highest priced books per publshrID to all be on the same line...

Comment: I would use the sql function DENSE_RANK() on your data. Then in an outer query fold up again on a PIVOT function based on other criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH BKS AS(
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by pb.publ_id order by BK.list_price DESC) AS RankN,
           PB.publ_id AS publ,
           CONVERT(varchar(25),book_id)+ ' '+ title AS Main
           FROM bkinfo.publishers AS PB
           INNER JOIN bkinfo.books AS BK ON PB.publ_id = BK.publ_id
           )
SELECT BKS.publ,
       max(CASE WHEN RankN = 1 THEN MAIN END) AS a,
       max(CASE WHEN RankN = 2 THEN MAIN END) AS b,
       max(CASE WHEN RankN = 3 THEN MAIN END) AS c,
       max(CASE WHEN RankN = 4 THEN MAIN END) AS d
FROM BKS
GROUP BY BKS.publ
```

Comment: Because each `BKS.publ` group only has one `MAIN` value per Rank, and the `Max` of a single value is that value. This is also true of `Min`, which would work here as well. :)